# Add Option to Centre Images on Content Pages

Tags: 7, nodes, media

Currently, to align images only Right & Left options are available as shown in below image:

[image: Image Properties]

How to Enable full-width images similar to the link which is displaying images: https://medium.com/perspectives-from-the-economist-intelligence-unit/lake-chads-twofold-crisis-27545789e9d7

Answer (score 0):

With CK Editor Module. Install CK EDITOR Image module, which enables the third alignment option to center the image also.

Here is the link to download the Module. https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_image

***Note:*** CK EditorImage only supports for Drupal 7 and its previous versions.